# MySQL and PHP Select Option with information from database

Tags: php, mysql

This is my project 
so far I have this I took the code from part of my project

```html
<?php  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Call Ins </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/employee_number_autocomplete.js"></script>


<link href="css/create.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('http://a0319p528/new_callins/images/background.jpg')">
<div align="center">
</div>
<h1 class="h1">Call Ins Entry Page<br><br></h1>
<div align="center">
<form action = "insert_process.php" method ="post" class="form" style="width: 700px; height: 575px">
<br><br><br><br><br>

 <table style="width: 81%">
<tr> 
 <!--start of Scheduled Date--!>
 <td style="width: 133px">Scheduled Date</td>
 <td style="width: 152px">
 <input name="Date_Scheduled" id="Date_Scheduled" type="text"value="<?php  echo date("M j, Y - g:i"); ?>"/>
</td>
 <!--end of Scheduled Date--!>
 <!--start of reason--!>
 <td style="width: 159px">Reason</td>
<td>
 <select name ="Reason" style="width: 160px" >
 <option value ="">Please select ...</option></select>
</td></tr>
 <!--end of reason--!>
 <!--start of Employee Name--!>   
<tr>
 <td style="width: 133px">Employee Name</td>
 <td style="width: 152px">
 <input type="text" id="Employee_Name" name="Employee_Name">
</td>
 <!--end of Employee Name--!>
 <!--start of Contact--!>
 <td style="width: 159px">Contact</td><td>
 <select name ="Contact" style="width: 160px">
 <option value ="">Please select ...</option></select>
</td></tr>
 <!--end of Contact--!>
 <!--start of Employee Number--!>
<tr>
      <td style="width: 133px">Employee Number</td>
 <td style="width: 152px">
 <input type="text" id="Employee_Number" name="Employee_Number" ></td>
 <!--end of Employee Number--!>
 <!--start of Approval--!> 
 <td style="width: 159px">Approval</td>
<td>
 <select name ="Approval" style="width: 160px">
 <option value ="">Please select ...</option></select>
</td>
</tr>
 <!--end of Approval--!>
<tr>
 <td style="width: 133px">Time_Reported</td>
 <td style="width: 152px"><input name="Time_Reported" id="Time_Reported" type="text"value="<?php  echo date("M j, Y - g:i"); ?>"/></td>
</td>
 <!--end of Approval--!>
 <!--start of Scheduled Area--!>
 <td style="width: 159px">Scheduled Area</td>
 <td><select name ="Scheduled_Area" style="width: 160px" >
 <option value ="">Please select ...</option></select></td>
</tr>
 <!--end of Scheduled Area --!>
 </table>
<br>
 <input type="submit" value= "Submit Request "><br><br><br><br>
 <!--start of yes or no Checkbox--!>
 <p class="style1">Do not check Box bellow human resources use only<strong>.</strong></p>
 <label>no</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="Complete" name="Complete" value="N">
 <label>yes</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="Complete" name="Complete" value="Y"> <br>
 <!--end of no or yes checkbox--!>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "systems399", "employees_db");
    $Employee_Name=  $_POST["Employee_Name"];
     $sql="SELECT * FROM  names WHERE FIRSTNAME='$Employee_Name'   ";
    $query= mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $rc= $row["EMPLOYEE_NUMBER"];
    echo json_encode ($rc);
 ?>
```

Is there a way to make a select option with mysql db and php

```html
<select name ="Employee Name" style="width: 160px" >
<option value ="">Please select ...</option></select>
```

But have the option value get the names from the two columns in the database Firstname and lastname. I will continue to Google it if anyone came across any examples or tutorials please share.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to figure it out by yourself at all? Any sample code? Or do you just want someone to work for you?

Comment: I am trying to figure it out for myself just wanted any examples oh wait my code did not show up on the post

Comment: If we did the entire thing for you, what would you learn? At least give it a try, show us some code, and we'll help where you're truly stuck.  Take the HTML example you just provided and try and populate it with a simple structure like a PHP array, if you figure out the basics of PHP first, database stuff will make more sense later.

Comment: I will try to figure it out I have been studying php a lot but didn't know where to start. I was looking for tutorial on an example. I will keep looking and read up some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a short example.

Right now, you'r code will give you 1 option

```
<select name ="Employee Name" style="width: 160px" >
<option value ="">Please select ...</option></select>
```

Let's take an array like:

```
$array = array('0' => 'test', '1' => 'test1');
```

To populate your array as options, you can simply do

```
<select>
<?php
foreach ($array as $a) {
?> 
<option value=""><?= $a ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

which will give you all values from your array as an option.

---

You can now go and fill your array with data from your db by

```
$con = new mysqli('HOST', 'DB_USER' , 'DB_PASS' , 'DB');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE");
if ($result = $con->query($sql)) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$array = array('0' => $row['row1'], '1' => $row['row2']);
}}
```

Now you have filled your array with the data from db and can populate this in your options as you want.

Comment: There's a little check mark below the number on the left side of the answer, turns green on hover, just click it

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you just want to select data from your database and use it in your HTML. This is a very basic question. If you don't know how to do this, I would recommend a "How to learn MySQL" book first. You won't have fun developing a website where you have to ask online for every line of code.

Edit: Okay, now there is some code. This should work:

```
<option value="<?php echo $rc; ?>"><?php echo $row["FIRSTNAME"]</option>
```

However, please don't use your code in a public website. It's not the topic of the question, but there is a huge SQL-Injection vulnerability in your code.

Comment: I was asking if anyone new of an example or tutorial not to actually do the work for me or book I will check that book out will I be able to do it with php. I know how to do this in asp.net 4.5 with no problem.

Comment: everyone keeps saying that i need to learn the proper way to have better security. Is there a book to learn proper security for mysql

Answer (score 1):

Well what you could do is from the client side have a dialog box for enter first name and last name and then pass those values to your php class and use those variables to select from the db.