# How to get the data for current Dateto show only

Tags: php, mysql

[image]I have this, but not sure how to get current date to show only. I also know that this needs to be fixed so it does not get SQL injection. Anyone have an idea what I can do to show the current date only of the records.

```html
$sql = "SELECT id, lanId, name, department, manager, request, request_description, request_comments, status, comments, compUser, compDt FROM requests WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh'CURDATE()";
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

This is on my admin page

```html
<tr>
  <td style="width: 125px"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame">xgrh</a></td>
  <td style="width: 125px" align="center"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame"><?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh'");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
echo $row['COUNT(*)'];  
} ?></a></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: What does  compUser='xgrh'CURDATE()";  mean?

Comment: also the date format is 10/27/14

Comment: The field in the table is compUser which is completed by user xgrh and then followed by the date for today. Sorry been trying different combinations to get the date in. But nothing has worked for me.

Comment: lowercase sorry had caps on.

Comment: The field where the date goes is called compDT  I tried this too $today = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "SELECT id, lanId, name, department, manager, request, request_description, request_comments, status, comments, compUser, compDt FROM requests WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh' And compDT="$today";
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Be more specific please, does my answer work or do you need it from another column?

Comment: Oh I think that may work. Give me one sec to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

**Set variable before query with entire string**

```
$user = 'xgrh'.Date('m/d/y');
```

**Query:**

```
$sql = "SELECT id, lanId, name, department, manager, request, request_description, request_comments, status, comments, compUser, compDt FROM requests WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='$user'";
```

you need to make sure what the exact used dateformat your date column is (days with leading zero or without, month with leading zero or without) and set the variables dateformat according.

If the query should be like in your last comment:

```
$date = Date('m/d/y');

    $sql = "SELECT id, lanId, name, department, manager, request, request_description, request_comments, status, comments, compUser, compDt FROM requsts WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh' AND compDT = '$date'";
```

This:

```
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 125px"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame">xgrh</a></td>
        <td style="width: 125px" align="center"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame"><?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh'");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
echo $row['COUNT(*)'];  
} ?></a></td>
    </tr>
```

is completely wrong. You want to

```
a) run a query
b) echo the result
```

You're totaly mixing stuff

Comment: I tried this it is not showing only current date like 10/26/14 it is showing all 10/24/14, 10/25/14, and 10/26/14

Comment: column is compDT and data in it  is example 09/10/14 or 10/26/14

Comment: Did you tried the second one? If yes and it's not working, you need to be more exact on which columns store which data

Comment: Ya didnt work status column stores COMPLETED, RECIEVED, INPROGRESS, OHHOLD CompUser column stores xgrh,zeap, and xjae COMPDt column stores the date. I wanted to see if i can filter it to get user, status, then todays date.

Comment: also I changed the spelling in compDT to compDt in case it was case sensitive cause i gave you the wrong spelling

Comment: The second query will give you all rows that are status -> complete, compUser -> xgrh, compDT -> today's date, formated like 10/27/14. You need to change compDT to compDt in the query and fetch the rows you want to echo after the query

Comment: I added the code for my admin page I have this on in a separate page. maybe that is causing it not to show correctly.

Comment: Well, of course you need to include the query to your file, but with echo $row['COUNT(*)'];  you won't echo the correct things. If you want to have an output of compDt, you need to do: echo $row['compDt'];

Comment: I added a pic of the site I want it to only show 2 for today

Comment: The second query will do exactly what you want, you just need to echo out the results. I have answered your question regarding mysql querys here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539091/mysql-and-php-select-option-with-information-from-database you can use that in the exact same way, only use a table's markdown instead of select

Comment: sorry Michael it was working I had the wrong page up. The only thing now I have is to fix the count. I need to pay attention more. Sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: you need to specify that in your query ( f.e. count(compDt) as cd ) and echo $row['cd'];

Comment: Im confused on the count How would I get it to show the 2 records for that one date

Comment: If you want an output of the integer 2, use what i wrote in the last comment. If you want to have the rows where the conditions are true, use the second query I wrote in my answer. The second query will only give you the records that have compDt = today's date

Comment: ( f.e. count(compDt) as cd ) and echo $row['cd']; was it this one I am bit confused how to write this in to while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
 
echo $row['COUNT(*)'];  
}

Comment: yes, add the other part in the query and instead of echo $row['COUNT(*)']; echo $row['cd'];

Comment: <tr>
  <td style="width: 125px"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame">xgrh</a></td>
  <td style="width: 125px" align="center"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame"><?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh'");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
echo $row['cd'];   
} ?></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>

Comment: I am missing were to put count(compDt) as cd )

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(compDt) as cd FROM requests WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh'");  Like this not sure if this is right not working

Comment: Well, the query seems to be correct, now you only have to echo $row['cd']; in your while loop

Comment: Thanks for the help I am going to take a break on this figure it out tomorrow. It was a big help

Comment: <tr>
  <td style="width: 125px"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame">xgrh</a></td>
  <td style="width: 125px" align="center"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame"><?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh' AND compDt= date('m/d/y')");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
echo $row['COUNT(*)'];  
} ?></a></td>
 </tr>

Comment: oh wait I noticed it stays at 0 still not working right